# transformers: how to use hugging face EncoderDecoderModel to do machine translation task?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, machine-translation

I have trained a EncoderDecoderModel from huggging face to do english-German translation task. I tried to overfit a small dataset (100 parallel sentences), and use `model.generate()` then `tokenizer.decode()` to perform the translation. However, the output seems to be proper German sentences, but it is definitely not the correct translation.

Here are the code for building the model

```
encoder_config = BertConfig()
decoder_config = BertConfig()
config = EncoderDecoderConfig.from_encoder_decoder_configs(encoder_config, decoder_config)
model = EncoderDecoderModel(config=config)
```

Here are the code for testing the model

```
model.eval()
input_ids = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode(input_text)).unsqueeze(0)
output_ids = model.generate(input_ids.to('cuda'), decoder_start_token_id=model.config.decoder.pad_token_id)
output_text = tokenizer.decode(output_ids[0])
```

Example input: "iron cement is a ready for use paste which is laid as a fillet by putty knife or finger in the mould edges ( corners ) of the steel ingot mould ."

Ground truth translation: "iron cement ist eine gebrauchs ##AT##-##AT## fertige Paste , die mit einem Spachtel oder den Fingern als Hohlkehle in die Formecken ( Winkel ) der Stahlguss -Kokille aufgetragen wird ."

What the model outputs after trained 100 epochs: "[S] wenn sie den unten stehenden link anklicken, sehen sie ein video uber die erstellung ansprechender illustrationen in quarkxpress" which is totally nonesense.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Is this example part of the training dataset you used for overfitting? How was the loss during these 100 epochs? Did it decline?

Comment: yes the loss declined to close zero, but the model fails to output the correct sentences

Comment: I would suspect the problem is here: `decoder_start_token_id=model.config.decoder.pad_token_id`. How do you preprocess the target-side data? What symbols do you use to mark the beginning and the end of the sequence?

Comment: I didn't specify any symbols for the beginning and the end of the sequence. The input is just a sentence and the output also.